# No port serf found in the index; can't rebuild

Tags: macos, macports, npm

I'm trying to install npm port package but when I run the command "sudo port install npm" the bash shows error message below, and repeat the same error infinitely.

```
Warning: No port serf found in the index; can't rebuild
--->  Found 0 broken port(s), determining rebuild order
--->  Rebuilding in order
--->  Scanning binaries for linking errors: 100.0%
--->  Found 2 broken file(s), matching files to ports
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: I cannot see a port for serf there at all - why fo you think there is one? `port search serf` returns serf0, serf1 and zope-groupuserfolder perhaps one of these is what you want

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To fix this problem I made a port cleanup and deactivate, the steps:

```
sudo port clean serf
sudo port -f deactivate serf
sudo port install serf
```

Following the steps above my problem was solved.

Answer (score 3):

I just tried the deactivating trick and saw this:

```
$ sudo port clean serf
Warning: Skipping serf (not in the ports tree)
$ sudo port -f deactivate serf
--->  Deactivating serf @0.3.0_0
$ sudo port install serf
Warning: Skipping serf (not in the ports tree)
--->  Scanning binaries for linking errors: 100.0%
--->  No broken files found.
$
```

In spite of the fact that serf isn't in the ports tree, things now seem all better.